# How do I create a new structure in Screeps

Tags: javascript, screeps

So, this is a question about the game [screeps](http://screeps.com/). I know that in the simulation, I can create a road by going to the Construct menu on the left, but is there an API reference I can use to create one programmatically? My goal is to have a script that will automatically lay down construction sites between target A and target B. Has anyone found such a reference in the docs?

(I would tag this question with the screeps tag, but it appears I cannot do so with my current reputation. If this is the wrong place to post, please direct me to the right place, I just came here from the screeps website)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**UPDATED:** A method [`Room.createConstructionSite`](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#createConstructionSite) has been added to the API today ([changelog](http://screeps.com/docs/changelog.php)). Sample usage:

```
Game.rooms[roomName].createConstructionSite(10, 15, STRUCTURE_ROAD);
```

> **OLD POST**: A developer of Screeps is here. Indeed, there is no such API yet, but we plan to add it very soon. I will by update my answer when it is done.

Comment: Thanks! It's a fun game, and I can't wait to see more of it

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the Screeps API (http://screeps.com/docs/index.php) and I don't think it's possible to create structures programmatically.