# Is there any way to automate construction?

Tags: javascript, screeps

Is there currently a way to automate construction in the game? If there is not a way, are we allowed to use external scripts to do this for us in the multiplayer version?

Comment: See here for more information. 

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051872/how-do-i-create-a-new-structure-in-screeps/27054679#27054679][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051872/how-do-i-create-a-new-structure-in-screeps/27054679#27054679

Comment: Please go through [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Despite negative mark on the question I've decided to share my solution for this.

I've defined module containing: 
 - list of creeps that I want to exist (names and body) for each spawn point,
 - script for creating them in given order and recreating destroyed creeps.

I use it like this:

```
var spawn = require('spawn_main');
spawn();
```

spawn_main's code (explanations in comments in the code):

```
module.exports = function () {
    var preDef = { //predefined creep classes (body and memory)
        harvester:{body: [Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE], memory: {role: 'harvester'}},
        collector:{body: [Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE, Game.MOVE], memory: {role: 'collector'}},
        guard:{body: [Game.TOUGH, Game.ATTACK, Game.MOVE, Game.MOVE], memory:{role: 'guard'}},
        healer:{body: [Game.HEAL, Game.HEAL, Game.MOVE, Game.MOVE], memory:{role: 'healer'}},
        tower:{body: [Game.RANGED_ATTACK, Game.RANGED_ATTACK, Game.MOVE], memory:{role: 'tower'}},
        builder:{body: [Game.WORK, Game.WORK, Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE], memory:{role: 'builder'}},
        hunter: {body: [Game.MOVE, Game.RANGED_ATTACK, Game.MOVE, Game.ATTACK], memory:{role: 'hunter'}}
    };
    var creeps = { //list of creeps I want to exist
        Harvester1: preDef.collector,
        Harvester2: preDef.harvester,
        Tower1: preDef.tower,
        Healer1: {body: [Game.HEAL, Game.HEAL, Game.MOVE, Game.MOVE], memory:{follow_role: 'tower',role: 'healer'}},
        Hunter1: preDef.hunter,
        Harvester3: preDef.harvester,
        Tower2: preDef.tower,
        Hunter2: preDef.hunter,
        Hunter3: preDef.hunter,
        Hunter4: preDef.hunter,
        Hunter5: preDef.hunter
    };

    for (var i in Game.spawns){ //for each spawn point
        var spawn = Game.spawns[i];
        // crowder pointed out bug in "if (null !== spawn.spawning) continue;"
        // changed from 'break;' to 'continue;'
        if (null !== spawn.spawning) continue; //spawn point can't be busy
        for (var name in creeps){ //for each 'to-be-created' creep
            // final name of the creep is [spawn_name]+[to_be_created_creep_name]
            if (undefined === Game.creeps[i+name]){ //if creep does not exist
                var mem = {};
                for (var attr in creeps[name].memory) {mem[attr] = creeps[name].memory[attr]; } //copy memory field
                mem.home_name = i; // assign name of spawn point to which creep will be returning 
                spawn.createCreep(creeps[name].body, i+name, mem); //create new creep with defined body, name and memory
                break; //ignore rest of 'to-be-created' creeps (spawn point should be busy). This also prevents creating creeps out of order
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You probably want "continue;" in your for .. in spawns loop on the spawning condition, rather than break -- otherwise you'll never evaluate the rest of the spawners if your first spawner is working.

Comment: I'm quite positive I wanted to make 'break;'. 'Break' is affecting only creep loop. Spawn loop will be unaffected.
Test code:

    var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    for(var i in a){
        for(var j in a){break;}
        console.log(i);
    }

Comment: How does "if (null !== spawn.spawning) break; //spawn point can't be busy" affect only the creep loop? It's not even in that loop.

Comment: Oooh, you mean this break; I have not noticed it (and was talking about break; inside creep loop. Yes, most definitely, I wanted to make 'continue;' there. Thank you.